# How to mark numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need to mark numbers on HTML page. I know how to mark numbers, but how can I recognize **decimal** numbers? I need to mark every number in range. Like this: [range 1-3]

```
This is number 1, this is number 1.8 and this is 8.2. It should also mark number 3.
```

How can I mark it using javascript (without jQuery)?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: What if your text is like `foo 1.2.3.4.5 bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for changing the numbers.

```js
var node = document.getElementById('text');

node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)+/g, function (s) {
    return s >= 1 && s <= 3 ? '<strong>' + s + '</strong>' : s;
});
```

```html
<div id="text">This is number 1, this is number 1.8 and this is 8.2. It should also mark number 3.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and find numbers matching your criteria in a loop

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.split(/\s/)
  .map(v => {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(v)) && parseFloat(v) <= 3) {
      var res = parseFloat(v);
      var rest = new RegExp(res, "g");
      return "<strong>" + res + "</strong>" + v.replace(rest, "");
    }

    return v;
  }).join(" ");
```

```html
<div id="div">
This is number 1, this is number 1.8 and this is 8.2. It should also mark number 3.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But Nina Scholz was faster and her code looks better, so I've marked her answer as the best. But this works too, so thx :)